# My app is deamnding modules I dont need! What is my problem?

Tags: react-native, expo

My expo app worked perfectly for a long time. Then I installed React-Navigation and now I get errors that I'm missing modules I don't need like react-native-gesture-handler. I installed that and now it needs react-native-screens. I can't just continue installing shit I don't need. So what is my Problem?

Error message:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module react-native-screens from C:\Users\***\test\node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\views\Screens.tsx: react-native-screens could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  2 | import { Animated, View, ViewProps } from 'react-native';
  3 |
> 4 | let Screens: typeof import('react-native-screens') | undefined;
    |                             ^
  5 |
  6 | try {
  7 |   Screens = require('react-native-screens');
```

EDIT: I know see that I might need the module. And I've checked and it's there, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is needed for React Navigation it needs this extra modules! Just follow:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started - the docs there are even specifying the installation when using expo.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the Issue. I did a stupid and called the wrong component. Thanks

Comment: @bebo7 No worries, please consider to accept my answer so that this issue is completed. Have a good weekend and good luck on further programming.